# What type of statistics question is this and which equation do I apply?

Tags: statistics

Sofia and Tess will each randomly choose one of the 10 integers from 1 to 10. What is the probability that neither integer chosen will be the square of the other ?

Comment: How do they pick a number? Are there 10 numbered marbles in a hat? Can they both pick the same number or not? (with or without replacement)

Comment: How many ways are there such that they COULD have chosen a square of the other? There's not many ways to do this, so it's possible to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question itself says : '*Find the probability ..*' It means you have to find a way to find favourable cases and total cases, and probability is simply their ratio.You can proceed as I have done below :

Since they are not disallowed to pick same integer :

**Total cases:** $\underbrace{10}_{\text{For Sofia}} \times \underbrace{10}_{\text{For Tess}} = 100$

**Unfavourable cases** : $ (1,1) , (2,4), (4,2), (3,9), (9,3)= 5~ \text{cases}$

*Note :* I have selected ordered pairs since selection of $2$ by Sofia and $4$ by Tess is different from $2$ by Tess and $4$ by Sofia.Similarly for others.But selection of  $(1,1)$ is symmetric

**Favourable Cases :** $\text {Total Cases - Unfavourable Cases} =100 - 5$

$$\text{ Probability} = \frac{~~\text{No. of Favourable Cases}~~}{\text{No. of Total Cases}} =\frac{95}{100}=\frac{19}{20}$$

Comment: Thank you so much !! I love the break down of everything. Quick question, is this something that I should be able to pull out of my brain or better question, how would I be able to recognize this type of question ?

Comment: When ever you have a total amount compared to a smaller amount of the total amount you can use the proportion formula.

Comment: @TiaraHoward You can see my edit.